# Can you change the add-in filename without changing the Visual Studio project name?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, add-in

My solution has several projects in it, one of which is an Add-in project, and I'd like to keep the naming convention of all of the projects intact but change the filename of the generated .esriaddin file.  Can the generated .esriaddin filename be changed automatically without without changing the Visual Studio project name or do I need to make a post-build event to rename it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the .esriaddin file name (e.g. Myfilenewfile.esriaddin) in windows explorer to whatever you want, however it will be referenced in ArcMap as the command name that you defined within the Config.esriaddinx file.  By default the addin file name matches the Project>Properties>Application>Assembly/Root name.

Comment: That's what I figured. I was hoping to stay away from changing the assembly name and only changing the addin file name, but I see that's not possible, at least without a post-built event.  Thanks.